# Ionic testing - asynchronous look for a change in ionViewDidLoad

Tags: ionic-framework, jasmine

I have troubles trying to test the value of a variable that change inside the *ionViewDidLoad* method

welcomepage.ts

```
@Component({...})
export class WelcomePage {

    test: number = 0;

    constructor(){}

    ionViewDidLoad(){
        this.test = 1;
    }

}
```

welcomepage.spec.ts

```
    it('test should equal be equal to 1', () => {
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(component.test).toBe(1)
    });
```

But this test is not succeeding. If I do the change inside the constructor function (`this.test = 1`) then it is working.

======== UPDATE ========

It seems that it is a problem with ionViewDidLoad function triggered by ionic, it is working as usual by running ionic but not in the test.

Comment: .. what is your question? your variable is `test` of _type_ `number`. you are trying to set `this.number` value in `ionViewDidLoad`.

Comment: try `console.log(this.test)` to check if test variable is set or not

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake by copy/paste I corrected I was trying to set the test variable. I can not see the log output when runing "npm test", but with "ionic serve" everything work

Answer (score 1):

It appears that ionic life-cycle events (ionViewDidEnter, ionViewDidLoad, ...) are not called during testing, by calling it manually it works :

```
it('test should equal be equal to 1', () => {
    component.ionViewDidLoad();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.test).toBe(1)
});
```

But then how are we sure that ionic really call ionViewDidLoad ?

Answer (score 0):

Your variable is not setting because you have done it in wrong way. Your variable name is test and you are setting value in variable type which is `number`. Please see the following snippet, hope it helps.

```
@Component({...})
export class WelcomePage {

   test: number = 0;

   constructor(){}

   ionViewDidLoad(){
       this.test = 1;
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes sorry I made a mistake when writing the code, I corrected it, but this is not the problem. Jasmine test does not see the change of value of the variable test.